# How to rewrite two dimensional array slicing using loops(open cv format)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to get a particular area(not a rectangle) from an image. From the contour, I was able to generate all the points containing the area.

```
arialpoints = [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2]...]
```

I'm going through an example in opencv which created an image based on topleft x,y coordinates and width height

```
testimage = cv2.imread("foo.jpg")
cropped = testimage[x:x+width, y:y+height]
cv2.imwrite('final.jpg', cropped)
```

But this is for rectangular cropped area, I would like to do it for the polygon. Is there a way where I can generate the testimage[x:x+width, y:y+height] from my coordinates?

Comment: How about finding the bounding box and then masking masking outside of your boundary? Or fill it with nan for plotting.

Comment: The area eventually retrieved would be rectangular, correct? You'd just be taking "points within the polygon" and computing the bounding box of that set, right?

Comment: Yes will be only taking the points inside the bounding box making everything outside transparent

Comment: Edit: Yes will be only taking the points inside the bounding box making points between current contour and bounding box transparent

Comment: @anishtain4 Interesting approach, will try that if I'm not able to solve this

Comment: So if I've understood correctly, the question is to find the `min` and `max` of the inner lists?

Comment: Nope, I have the area points of the polygon(contour), I need to plot it. Using min and max only gives me image inside bounding rectangle of the polygon. I need image inside the polygon(already have coordinates of all the pixels)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try with an example.

Let's say we have a random image

```
np.random.seed(42)
img = np.random.randint(255, size=(10,10,3))
```

[image]

and a list of points

```
points = np.array([[2, 2],
                   [3, 2],
                   [3, 3],
                   [4, 2],
                   [4, 3],
                   [5, 2],
                   [5, 3],
                   [5, 4],
                   [6, 5],
                   [7, 6]])
```

You can create a binary mask for your points like this (you might have to `np.fliplr(points)` depending on how x and y coordinates are defined)

```
mask = np.zeros_like(img)
mask[points.T.tolist()] = 1
```

[image]

You can now use this mask to select the area of the image you want

```
img = img * mask
```

[image]

and you can also limit your selection to your bounding box

```
xmin, ymin = np.min(points, axis=0)
xmax, ymax = np.max(points, axis=0)

cropped = img[xmin:xmax+1, ymin:ymax+1]
```

[image]

Comment: I have implemented the above solution,it's working as expected thanks, would like to know if there's a small tweak to change the background to transparent rather than black

Comment: @Saikiran it should still work if your image has an alpha channel. If it doesn't you could add one with `img = np.dstack((img, 255 * np.ones((img.shape[:2]))))` (assuming alpha is the last column, which it is by default with opencv)